# Georeferencing xyz layer from Griffiths Valuation of 1850s?

Tags: tiles, qgis-3, united-kingdom, history, ireland

[image: Griffiths Map with OSMIE]

I have made progress on my project to map land and property owned by individuals in 1850 in Ireland using Griffiths Valuation maps.  I used http://griffiths.askaboutireland.ie/gv4/single_layer/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg  with the help of @Steven Kay.  The townlands with beautiful Gaelic names and their borders are shown above in green from OSMIE in comparison with the Griffiths equivalents in red.  There is a difference at the borders which is slightly variable, as expected, from maps separated in time and projection by 160 years.  However, there is a noticeable and fairly constant shift of about 100m. This is most likely caused by something related to projections.

I now intend to create a vector layer which provides the actual property outline of each holder in an overlay.  If I proceed without correcting, the more modern satellite maps like Google Earth and Bing, will not line up properly with the outlines of land and building that I create.

I realize I could use georeferencing to correct this slight misalignment by recording sections of the Griffiths layer as .tif files.  I have already done so with a simple linear transformation of a small area which provides excellent corrected results.  I have tried to insert the corrected projection into the Griffiths layer, but it has no effect.  So, I would like to find a foolproof method of either georeferencing such xyz layers or correcting the projection in the Griffiths layer as it is used.   I just love the convenience of the tiled Griffiths layers I have and the details they provide all over Ireland.

In summary, is there a QGIS process methodology to georeference tiled xyz layers on a server if a final correcting projection is known?

I imagine there is a simple way to do this that a beginner like me is missing.

Comment: This might be a datum shift issue. Unfortunately, creating a custom CRS makes it even worse due to the Web Mercator hack. XYZ layers seem to depend on that to display properly.

Comment: Yes to a datum shift issue.  I have tried other CRS types including OSNI1952 and TM65, but no joy @AndreJ.  I imagine this is related to the downloaded data which is already in 
CRS EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator - Projected and prevents going back to the original OS data of the 1850s map.  I did notice that the reason for reverting to the project CRS when I tried to use the custom correction CRS with the xyz layer was the absence of a "projection specification", including no extent.  I intend to check this out. I now suspect this is a complex issue even for map historians.

Comment: It would be much easier if the old map was in a "well.known" CRS like IRENET95 or WGS84 UTM. What you can try is export a screenshot to PNG, reproject it from EPSG:3857 to UTM, then apply the datum shift to that,